# Connecting Libvirt VM's (Domain XML config) to OpenVSwitch

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, openstack

I'm trying to learn OVS and KVM, and generally make sense of basic bridge networking in the virtual world (i.e. between OVS, the VM Host and KVM/Libvirt guests). I'm using ClearLinux (systemd based) on the VM host.

My **actual question is in bold further down**, the rest of this post is to hopefully help people advise me on it.

EDIT:

---

Got pointed to SU from the Network Engineering StackExchange.
If anyone knows any good training courses on OVS and KVM, please let me know :-)

---

References thus far:
https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html
http://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/howto/libvirt/

So, I have got to the point of:

1. Having an ovs bridge (testbridge)
2. Connected the host's physical ethernet (enp5s0) to testbridge
3. Created two virtual tap devices (virtualport1 and 2)
4. Connected the taps to the testbridge

OVS looks like this:

```
sudo ovs-vsctl show

010aff41-dc37-410d-87dc-842a1a2cebeb
    Bridge testbridge
        Port "virtualport2"
            Interface "virtualport2"
        Port "enp5s0"
            Interface "enp5s0"
        Port testbridge
            Interface testbridge
                type: internal
        Port "vnet0"
            Interface "vnet0"
        Port "virtualport1"
            Interface "virtualport1"
    ovs_version: "2.8.1"
```

'enp5s0' is the physical port on the vm host. It is connected to a Cisco SG-300 (switchport general interface, trunking a bunch of vlans, general pvid of 25 and vlan 25 is untagged).

There is an external DHCP server working on all the relevant VLANS.

I have a libvirt guest called 'debian' (bonus marks for creativity) that is configured with:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address="00:16:3E:EF:61:91"/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <source bridge='testbridge'/>
  <virtualport type='openvswitch'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
<graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' sharePolicy='allow-exclusive' passwd='PleaseDontHaxorMe'>
  <listen type='address' listen='0.0.0.0'/>
</graphics>
```

Anyway, here is where I'm stuck. My question:
**How do I get some L3 joy going on at the vnet0 interface (i.e. at the guest vm 'debian'), so I have an IP to VNC in to, in order to conduct the install (I'm using the debian netinst.iso)?**

Having never done this before, I sort of assumed that it would arp and come up via DHCP and *ip address show vnet0* would show the address of VM to VNC to it...Obviously not though. It sort of looks like it's up at L2 (as below):

```
ip address show vnet0
16: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq master ovs-system state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:16:3e:ef:61:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc16:3eff:feef:6191/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But doing a:

```
sudo ovs-appctl fdb/show testbridge
```

Only seems to list mac's on Port 1 (enp5s0) not vnet0...

If I can get that going, I also wanted to learn how to configure 'vnet0' on the ovs testbridge:

1. As an access port in vlan 100?
2. As a trunk port, on vlan 100, 150 and 151?
3. To trunk any/all tagged vlans to that exist on testbridge?
4. Same as 3, but including untagged vlans?

**EDIT 3:**

---

https://blog.scottlowe.org/2012/11/07/using-vlans-with-ovs-and-libvirt/
This pretty much covers the above, points. Also looks at how to use the libvirt domain xml to patch in a VM. Haven't finished it all yet, will test it tomorrow.

---

That said, I can probably work these last 4 things out myself if I can get a VM going in the first place to sniff traffic on vnet0 and see what is actually going on...

NOTE:
I had intended to connect the VM to virtualport1 but missed that somewhere and instead it created a new port on testbridge called 'vnet0'. Pretty sure that's fixable in the libvirt domainxml with the ovs parameters here (will tidy it up later, for now, vnet0 it is!):
https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsNICSBridge

**EDIT 2:**

---

I think this bit is solved as per the above link by:

Pull the uuid of the relevant port you want to attach to:

```
sudo ovs-vsctl list Port | grep 'name\|_uuid'
```

Add it to the Libvirt domain XML of relevant VM:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address="00:16:3E:EF:61:91"/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <source bridge='testbridge'/>
  <virtualport type='openvswitch'/>
    <parameters interfaceid='YOUR_UUID_GOES_HERE'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

---

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out I [XY'd this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) something horrible....

Everything was working, I just had no idea how to go about the headless install. Turns out, that doing so is an easy matter of SSH port forwarding as covered:

- https://blog.scottlowe.org/2012/08/21/working-with-kvm-guests
- https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/08/21/accessing-vnc-consoles-of-kvm-guests-via-ssh/
- https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/10/adjusting-vnc-console-access-via-libvirt-xml/

Read all about VM domain XML config (the  element with respect to VNC in particular) here:

- http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html

Some quick notes on that though:

```
VNC Notes:
* Default - Guest binds it's VNC server to hosts loopback:
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes'/>
* The first guest gets screen 0/port 5900, the second guest gets screen 1/port 5901 etc.
* Requires SSH tunneling in order to gain access to the guest domain’s VNC console.
Better VNC Options:
    Guest listens on any host interface, port auto allocated:
        <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' listen='0.0.0.0'/>
    Guest listens on specified IP, port auto allocated, password protected:
        <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' passwd='correcthorsebatterystaple'>
          <listen type='address' address='192.168.120.15'/>
        </graphics>
    Guest listens on specified IP and port, password protected with screen share policy:
        <graphics type='vnc' port='5904' listen='192.168.120.15' sharePolicy='allow-exclusive' passwd='correcthorsebatterystaple'>
          <listen type='address'  listen='192.168.120.15'/>
        </graphics>
    Guest listens on specified IP, auto websocket, password protected with screen share policy:
        <graphics type='vnc' websocket='-1' listen='192.168.120.15' sharePolicy='allow-exclusive' passwd='correcthorsebatterystaple'>
          <listen type='address'  listen='192.168.120.15'/>
        </graphics>
```

**In summary:**
Make sure you have the VM Domain XML  element correctly setup for VNC and that you are using a netinst iso.
Configure your OVS bridge (if that is what you are using for the VM). Define a libvirt network XML. Then in the VM domain definition XML, connect it to the previously defined libvirt network that makes use of your OVS bridge.

Check the VM's listening port (noting that it is relative to the default, :0 means all IPs on 5900, 127.0.0.1:1 would mean localhost on 5901 etc).

```
sudo virsh vncdisplay $VM_NAME
```

SSH forward an interface to the VM, which generically looks like:

```
ssh -N -L HOST_IP:HOST_PORT:localhost:5900 user@kvmhost
```

Forwarding Localhost 5901 to VM 5900:

```
ssh -N -L 5901:localhost:5900 user@kvmhost
```

Forwarding a specific external IP on the host to the VM. the '-fNT' is used to background the SSH forward without actually stopping the process, thus freeing up the console session to keep using it:

```
ssh -fNT -L 192.168.225.17:5901:localhost:5900 user@kvmhost
```